# control consume speed of celery worker

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to set up Celery with my Django app. This app will let user call some API and get the response. However this API has limitation that only allow user to call it not more than once per second.

So I am planning to use celery to control the calling frequency. Multiple users might use this app at the same time, so I think I should set up the calling part as worker. Everybody can submit requests to call the API into queue, worker will consume them.

Here is the question: how can I limit the work to consume the task(i.e. send the api request) as 1 per second?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

celery tasks have a [rate_limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit) option that should do what you want. This is per-worker so you'll need to use a dedicated queue to ensure that all requests for this task got the the one worker.

Comment: even if you specify a  queue for this rate limited task i am assuming only one worker can work on it